# How can I run just the statement my cursor is on in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, editor

As a long time Toad for Oracle user, I have gotten used to hitting Ctrl+Enter and having just the statement under the cursor be executed.

In SQL Server Management Studio, hitting F5 runs the entire script. To run just the current statement, I have to manually highlight the statement I want, and then hit F5.

That is really annoying to me. Does anyone know of a tool with a keyboard shortcut to run just the current statement on a SQL Server? I would change tools just for this one feature.

Note: Oddly enough, even the free [Toad for SQL Server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm) does not let you run just the statement under the cursor.

Comment: Note on your note:  In TOAD, the F9 key runs the current statement(s) group.  Groups are separated by using the "go" keyword (also answered by "ercan").

Comment: F9 runs just the current statement in the later versions of TOAD (v6.6++).  Statements are optionally be separated by semicolons.  Its 95% trustworthy in being able to know where the statement ends even when there is no semicolon.

Comment: Ten years later this is still an issue. Just coming from SQL Developer and I'm shocked I should really make a tedious workaround for this even now. Any recent solution perhaps?

Comment: @MattSom I wish!

Comment: @MattSom, I have found the latest version of SSMSExecutor to work well with the latest SSMS, if you are still looking for something.  I have a huge list of complaints about SSMS, but I'm glad to have a workaround for this one after 13 years.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can check out this add-in for SSMS 2012. Place the cursor within the statement you want to execute and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

[SSMS Executor - https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor/releases](https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor/releases)

**Update:**
Project moved to github and the addin re-written to support SSMS 2014, SSMS 2016. (Previously, the project lived on codeplex, at [SSMS Executor - http://ssmsexecutor.codeplex.com/](http://ssmsexecutor.codeplex.com/).)

Comment: This worked really well for me in SSMS2012, but now I'm running SSMS2014 and I **really** miss it!  Anyone know of a SSMS2014 solution?

Comment: Hi **samp** I am reworking the tool for SSMS2014. Will let you know when ready.

Comment: Looking forward to it!

Comment: @st.stoqnov - I would love to use this addin but we're running SSMS 2013.  When do you plan to support this version?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @namford the project was moved to github and the addin rewritten to support SSMS 2014/2016.

Comment: Hi @samp the project was moved to github and the addin rewritten to support SSMS 2014/2016.

Comment: Is it possible to select the text when we run current statement? I looked in the code and looks there is code to select but doesn't be actually selecting text in SSMS. Btw, Really love this extension!

Comment: @StanislavStoyanov Please edit the question to mention that you're the author of the project that you're recommending.

Comment: It seems, that there is a problem with extension - https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor/issues I tried it too (version 17.4) and loading at startup failed...

Comment: I have this installed, but it's executing all the statements, and then putting them all in their own grid. Anyone know how to prevent that?

Comment: For SSMS v18.6, I get error ---> "Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Extensions\SSMSExecutor.dll assembly --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information" . Note 1) I manually created the Extensions folder under Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, it did not exist before. 2) I tried doing the install with SSMS shut down, still the problem exists. I do get a .tmf file added to that folder every time I try to run the msi. OS is Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This is the best one, and it's free. Works on multi line statements. Use the first link for Github.

Comment: Still works for me in SSMS 19.1. 
Installer didn't work, but I was able to add it manually by downloading .zip and extracting in Extensions-folder. 
I did have to manually "unblock" each file in Windows file-propperties though.

Comment: Comment from @ChrisJohansen saved the day for me when using SSMS 19.2. You can "unblock" the zip file after downloading so you don't have to do it for each file separately after copying to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19\Common7\IDE\Extensions"

Answer (score 51):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>KU</kbd> to select a line.
Then use <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it.

Although it only works for single line selection, still I find it quite useful.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Hey that's handy, for one liners.  Thanks

Comment: Or that and CTRL E

Comment: CTRL-E executed entire script in the file in SSMS 18.5

Answer (score 23):

*Ok, so what I'm getting from all these answers is "No, that is not possible."*

**Edit:**

Here is how I was able to do this:

1 - Download [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html)

2 - Download the [jTDS driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)

3 - Follow [these instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/thirdparty-095608.html) to add that driver to SQL Developer

4 - Connect to SQL Server using SQL Developer (cool!)

5 - Run it and life is good

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be considered the answer because these are all based on Oracle tools. The question was related to SSMS

Comment: [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) also allow this query between ; ; execution. And it's much more power then SQL Developer

Comment: @Jacques Single-line execution is the single feature that Oracle got right, and Microsoft didn't. Everything else about SQL Developer is sub-par, but it *does* integrate with MS SQL servers.

Comment: @Jacques as this is not easy to make working in SSMS, I'm happy there is this answer and for me this one seems to be the best (typically my queries are not one-liners, I do not prefer to write complex queries in one line just to make CTRL+KU working...)

Comment: You can actually use SQL Developer to run MSSQL-Server Queries. I don't think it's a good idea, however shame on you, Microsoft, for such a bad user experience.

Comment: This question is ancient, and I want to go on record as saying my solution presented in this answer was awkward-but-effective in 2009, but I no longer stand by it in 2022.  I've found SSMSExecutor to be a good solution, and it works in my current version of SSMS (18.12.1).

Answer (score 11):

Above answer helped me to create a shortcut to Execute current Statement without selecting the query

1 - Click on **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard**

2 - For **Show commands** containing, set it to **SqlComplete10.Common_ExecuteCurrentStatement**

3 - For Use new shortcut in, set it to **SQL Query Editor**

4 - For Press shortcut keys(desired shortcut key), perform the Ctrl-Enter combination.

5 - Click on **Assign**. Click on OK.

Comment: This does the trick, but I had to remove the shortcut from another command first, else it would simply not work.

Comment: How did you do that? When I following the instructions above ctl-enter just highlights the line (note my queries are on multiple lines).

Comment: Seems outdated.

Comment: @Matt I did find something when I searched for "Execute", namely, `Tools.ExecuteStatement`, which only works when I change its shortcut to Global.

Comment: @Matt Nope! Turns out, that was added by [this plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270849/712526), which *finally* started working.

Comment: This works but it requires that you install SQL Complete from devart and remove all other references to the shortcut you want to use. SSMS v17 --SQL Complete v5.9

Comment: Am using SQL server 2016 Management Studio and the query has changed from **SqlComplete10.Common_ExecuteCurrentStatement** to **SqlComplete.ExecuteCurrentStatement.**

Answer (score 9):

[Somebody suggested this features](http://devart.uservoice.com/forums/87893-dbforge-sql-complete/suggestions/1335977-add-a-feature-to-run-current-statement-?ref=title) on Devart dbForge SQL Complete (addon for Management Studio) , and  it's still in the development stage. Let's hope that it's finished and doesn't get abandoned halfway through development.

Comment: I just installed the free of charge version for Sqlserver14(?) and it seems to work. [Devart page] (https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/editions.html)

Comment: I used it till now.... now it's showing add everytime i launch visual studio.

Answer (score 7):

I used this work around; when code is not commented out

> Ctrl + K + U

(this command highlight current query line) and then

> Ctrl + E

(this run highlighted query).

It is useful when you want to run a single line query between some other lines like :

```
  Select top 100 * from [dbo].[Order]

  Select top 100 * from [dbo].[OrderItem]

  Select top 100 * from [dbo].[OrderStatus]
```

Answer (score 6):

> Note: Oddly enough, even the free Toad
>   for SQL Server does not let you run
>   just the statement under the cursor.

It is really annoying that TOAD does not hold to what it promises:

From TOAD help: *[F9 to execute] a portion of a statement, which can contain one or more statements. You can select the portion of the statement by placing the cursor within or adjacent to the statement, or by selecting the statement. 
Note: Toad considers "adjacent" all statements (including comments) separated from the cursor or from each other by fewer than two blank lines. If an error occurs during statement execution, an error message displays, allowing you to either ignore the error and continue or to abort execution.*

I tried it million times but it simply executes the whole script. I wanted to search for it in the user support group (toadss(at)yahoogroups.com) but yahoo has the stupidest search facility ever! It can't even find the keyword "toad" in the toad mail group, DOH!

I think TOAD is the best querying tool ever, but the lack of this feature really annoys me too.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION FOUND!**
I asked this issue in toadss mail group and got the answer. Unlike Oracle, you have to separate statements in SQL Server with the keyword **GO** after each statement. Only if you do that the F9 button works as expected, executing the current statement.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible to do using just the management studio.
BUT you can use keyboard shortcut software (e.g. http://www.autohotkey.com/) to have a special sequence recorded and assigned to a hotkey.
In your case you need:

```
<home><shift-end><F5>
```

This will select the current line and execute it.

Comment: This won't select the entire current (multiline) block however.

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> while text is highlighted.

Comment: Ok, but I still have to manually highlight what I want.  My real goal is to be able to type a statement and then hit some key that will execute just what is under the cursor.

Comment: for me, F5 is easier to hit while the text is highlighted then "CTRL-E".

Answer (score 4):

I use a workaround: I comment queries I'm not using. You can use CTRL-K, CTRL-C to comment the SQL you've highlighted. Use CTRL-K, CTRL-U to uncomment. That way, you can comment all other queries, and execute the one you're interested in with F5.

Comment: This is a total pain in the butt.  Why should a SQL Editor make me comment out everything I don't want?  Can I not just positively state "run this one command" without grabbing the mouse or pushing "Shift+Up" 35 times?

Comment: Just to clarify, thanks for the answer; I appreciate it.  I'm really just griping at the SQL Server Mgmt Studio interface.

Comment: If you find a better way, be sure to post it here :)

Comment: Total non-solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Toad for SQL Server the following default hot-keys can be used for execution:

- F5: Execute all SQL statements in editor
- F9: Execute SQL statement at current cursor position
- Shift-F9: Execute all SQL statements from cursor, including the current at cursor position

However, like 'ercan' wrote, you need to seperate/follow each statement with 'GO'.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM accounts
GO

SELECT TOP 5 * FROM users
GO

SELECT TOP 5 * FROM contracts
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature is present in [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com) add-in for SSMS (I am the developer of this add-in):

**Shift-F5** will select the current statement (which allows you to review what you are currently going to execute). Then you press **F5** and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is assignment for `CTRL` + `Enter` combination for action **Query.Execute** in `SQL Server Management Studio`.

1. Open **`Tools > Options`** menu.
2. Select **`Environment > Keyboard`** page in left pane.
3. Find **`Query.Execute`** action and select it.
4. Set **`SQL Query Editor`** in **`"Use new shortcut in:"`** dropdown list.
5. Now type **`CTRL + Enter`** combination in **`press shortcut keys:`** textbox.
6. Click the **`Assign`** button.
7. Change **`Shortcut currently used by:`** to **`Query.Execute (Ctrl+Enter (SQL Query Editor))`**
8. Click **`OK`**. `Done`.

Comment: To execute only the current line is selecting all line by end of the line with Shift+Home then execute Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: Isn't this the same as Shift+Home and then pressing F5, what is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: As you said, Shift+Home and then pressing F5. This is a huge step for executing statement/s. Users came from Oracle were used to press ctrl+enter or cmd+enter then here is a quick fix what I did for myself. You are free to use any combination or combinations. Which benefit do you want from this solution?

Comment: Ok fair enough, I found SSMS Executor to be easier and more effective when you have multi line statements

Comment: Not sure to use 3rd party extension for daily usage. Key mapping is a life saver for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the having to move your hand to the mouse part that bothers you, you can hold the Ctrl down while hitting an up or down arrow key to select a line at once.

Comment: You mean Shift, yes?

And that is tedious for larger statements.

Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Complete Express edition has this built in. But you don't get it without the custom intellisense.

(I got this from Salamander2007's post)

Comment: Without telling us how to do it, this isn't very useful

Answer (score 1):

If the executor add-on solution (in the top posted answer) isn't working properly, i got it to work for me (SSMS v17.8.1):
The add-on adds a command under tools: **Tools > Execute Inner Statement**.

You can assign a custom keyboard shortcut key to it by going to **Tools > Options > Keyboard** then search for "execute" in the 'Show commands containing:' and selecting **Tools.ExecuteInnerStatement**. 
Then just assign your desired keystroke(s) in the 'Press shortcut keys:' field and hit the Assign button.

Answer (score 1):

To run just a section of a larger script, try this ..

Steps:

1. Collapse the SQL statement you want to run by clicking the minus sign in the left margin next to the statement. That will show only the first line (with an ellipsis "..." to indicate more code not shown) and the ending ";" for the statement.
2. Highlight the line.
3. Press [F5] key.

That will run just the highlighted statement. If you want to run more than the one
statement at a time, collapse each statement and highlight all that you want to run, then click [F5]. 
It's a work-around, but still much easier than having to drag and highlight numerous lines of code every time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define macro in SSMSBoost
SSMSBoost/Settings/Macros:

Select free slot for your macro
in right panel fill caption (if you want)
add 2 commands to sequence:
SSMSBoost.SelectCurrentStatement
Query.Execute
assign youur favorite shortcut
and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JosephStyons but can not upvote or comment.  DBeaver, squirrel, PL/SQL Developer, Toad all have the option to execute a single statement.

In my case I use these other tools which all have the option but then when I us SQLServer Management Studio, I am at risk of inserting and/or deleting because I forgot to highlight the select statement.

This is not an option, it is a requirement.  However Microsoft refuses to acknowledge logical useful features needed by users but chooses to cater to useless and cosmetic features.

UPDATE:  I wonder if Microsoft and SQL Server users feel this bug is a "feature" because they are able to (forced to) chain SQL Statements together and all execute at once.  Perhaps that is why the request fall on deaf ears?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is developing Azure Data Studio as the preferred, cross-platform management tool these days. In fact, installing a recent version of SSMS also installs ADS.

Azure Data Studio can run the current query in a query window with `Ctrl+F5`. In a SQL Notebook the current cell is executed with  `F5`

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check it out, but the [list of "stick with SSMS if you..."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/faq?view=sql-server-ver15#when-should-i-use-azure-data-studio-or-sql-server-management-studio) includes several things I do routinely.  It sounds like I might be trading out one set of complaints for another.  but I'll try it with an open mind :)

Comment: @JosephStyons you already get ADS when you download SSMS so you already have both tools on your machine. True, ADS doesn't offer every feature found in SSMS but a *lot* of its features are far better already. And new features are only added in ADS.

Comment: @You are right - when i went to install it, it told me it was already installed.  SSMS has always been a garbage tool, so I'm definitely open to using this instead.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**Tim Farrar**'s answer is halfway there, but it is still mousework, so let's assign a keyboard shortcut, to make it 90% there.

SSMS About box here says:

SQL Server Management Studio v17.7

| Component name | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio | 14.0.17254.0 |
| Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools | 14.0.1016.251 |
| Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) | 10.0.14393.5850 |
| Microsoft MSXML | 3.0 6.0 |
| Microsoft Internet Explorer | 9.11.14393.0 |
| Microsoft .NET Framework | 4.0.30319.42000 |
| Operating System | 6.3.14393 |

- Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
- In the "Show commands containing:" box, enter: Outlining
- In the list below, select: Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion
- Click in the "Press shortcut keys:" and press Alt-O
  (or what you like. for me Alt-O was unused)
- Click OK.

Then in the editor, anywhere in your SQL statement

- press Alt-O -> the statement is collapsed in one line
- press Home, then Shift-Down to select the collapsed line.
- Then you can already press F5 to execute,
- or press Alt-O to expand back to see the selected statement,
  and press F5 to execute.

This is still not a single keystroke, but for me much better than scrolling around by mouse or selecting line by line by keyboard.

Maybe someone adds the missing bit of assigning one key to several commands.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use the command line tools sqlcmd and osql.  I did a lot of sybase all at the unix command line using a wrapper function that passed my command string into the equivalent (which i think was isql?).  I used vi to, so maybe I was just crazy then ;-)

Comment: Actually that won't help. SQLCMD will not send the command to SQL Server until the batch is ended. (Normally indicated with GO.)

Answer (score 0):

Just select (highlight) the single statement you want to run and hit F5.

Comment: From the Question: To run just the current statement, I have to manually highlight the statement I want, and then hit F5.

Comment: kinda like, just get out of your car and turn the front tires to point in the direction you want to go and hit the accelerator....

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two Tools as follow : SQL Complete from dbForce and AuhotHotkey.

With SQL Complete: you can execute the current statement at the cursor, by pressing the combination Ctrl Shift E

The reason that I used the AutoHotkey is to make life easier :-) by using just F6 to execute the current statement, by setting the following code in AutoHotkey script:

```
;SQL EXECUTE THE CURRENT STATEMENT
F6::
Send ^+E
return
```

And voilà you can execute any current statement at the cursor by just pressing F6

But sometimes, again my big problem is I mistakely press F5 instead of F6 :D

Answer (score 0):

Redgate's SQL Prompt extension for SSMS can do this.

It's not free but in my experience it's well worth having.  Better intellisense than the SSMS out of the box version, tab colouring, tab history (so valuable!), snippets, single statement (not just a single line) execution, and lots more.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> (arrow down) to select single row, save a button than
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>  :D lol.

Then use <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it.

Hope it help too..

Answer (score 0):

select the line you want to execute and click on the execute button

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me ... I use SSMS 2012

1 - Click on Tools > Options > Environment Keyboard

2 - For **Show commands containing**, set it to **Query.Execute**

3 - For **Use new shortcut in**, set it to **SQL Query Editor**

4 - For **Press shortcut keys**, perform the Ctrl-Enter combination.

5 - Click on Assign.  Click on OK.

Comment: That does the whole script - I just want the statement under the cursor.

Comment: Right on, sorry I misunderstood the question.