# SQL Management Studio - Execute current line

Tags: ssms

In SQL Server 2008 Management studio, I can hit F5 to execute everything in the current query window. I can also highlight a query, and hit F5 to run that highlighted query.

Instead of having to highlight a query, is there a way I can run the single query my cursor is on, or run a query my cursor is on up to a the first ';'?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272334/any-way-to-run-just-the-current-statement-on-sql-server

Comment: Good question. It would be very handy to have such a shortcut. I've used Toad for Oracle and HeidiSQL for MySQL ... and they both have this feature. Come on Microsoft - catch up!

Comment: I thought that maybe nobody has ever bothered to suggest this "must have" feature to Microsoft and looked for it at their Connect site. I found three suggestions asking for this feature. Apparently they have combined the three of them into [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/275503/more-ssms-keyboard-shortcuts-for-execution)
So those of you who want to save precious time, can you [vote for this feature](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/275503/more-ssms-keyboard-shortcuts-for-execution)?

Comment: @FredyMuñoz: this isn't an answer; its a comment.  Remember, StackOverflow isn't a forum.  You're free to leave this comment everywhere it is relevant, but please don't add it as an answer.  As for merging, that's reserved for exact-to-the-letter dupes (or, at least that's the way I roll).  As for questions that cover the same subject, [you should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no there is no such keyboard shortcut in the [MSDN list of keyboard shortcuts for SMSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx), and I don't see any way of recording a macro to do so.  The only solutions I've found require creating an add-in which is **quite** a bit of work for a little savings.

Comment: Thats too bad. I can live with highlighting the query, I just wanted to save some keystrokes. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think it's a little savings that adds up over time to be quite significant.

Comment: this answer inspired me to just write an autohotkey script.  It's funny I didn't even know I was missing this feature... but the AHK is so nice...  also I have it do down arrow so i can hit F6 and have it execute this row, then advance to next row and hit F6 again, voila...


I'm sending it to a Remote Desktop Connection so I detect that window... but here is my AutoHotKey .ahk file


`SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#IfWinActive .*Remote Desktop Connection.*
^+r::
Send,{Home}+{Down}{F5}
return`

Answer (score 11):

In options you can configure line numbers to be displayed, then you can just click on a line number, which will highlight the whole line.

Comment: +1 I actually never knew this! This is actually a solid alternative to the question being asked since technically there is no such feature provided by Microsoft.

Comment: This is by far the best solution for this problem

Comment: Yes, it is the best answer without add-ons!

Comment: For those wondering... Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Line numbers

Answer (score 6):

Install SQL Complete Express. Its an SSMS plugin that free (also a paid version) and it allows using CTRL+SHIFT+E to execute current statement, I have remapped it to F9 as I use Toad frequently too.

I tried several others but they either didn't work with SSMS 2012 or I just didn't get on with them.

I find the intellisense quicker than the built in version to.

Comment: Old, I know, but you have no idea how happy this made me. I had Toad for Oracle in my last job 2 years ago, and have been lamenting this feature since I moved to a SQL-only house.

Comment: I use sql developer, so i am using Ctrl+Enter (^_^)

Answer (score 6):

If you are able to use SSMS 2012 then you can use the [SSMS Executor](https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor) add in as mentioned by [st-stoqnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178918/st-stoqnov) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270849/601758) to a similar question.

An [Alpha release](https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor/releases) is also available for SSMS 2014/2016/2017.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL after concluding a statement and as along as your cursor is at the end of the line all you have to do it hit `SHIFT+HOME` and it will highlight the entire statement and you can then proceed to press f5....

Comment: This selects everything up to the top of the file, in SQL Management Studio 2008, not just the current statement

Comment: Shift+Home, not Ctrl+Shift+Home :)

Comment: This assumes your query is only written on one line. This does not work for multi line queries

Answer (score 0):

For keyboard users:

I found going down with the cursor to the end of the query line, or the line bellow if it is empty, and then using "SHIFT + arrow up" to select the full query. After selection hit f5

Answer (score 0):

The new SQL Prompt has this feature. You press `SHIFT+F5` and the statement that your cursor is currently on will be executed. That's a big time saver and a feature that should have been there from the start in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed [Devart's Sql complete express](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/editions.html) that is free of charge. With ctrl-shift-e it does what you want.

Now I just need to swap, to make ctrl-e execute current and ctrl-shift-e everything...