# SSMS: keyboard shortcut to execute current row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio: Is there a way to execute current row (keyboard shortcut) without highlighting it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Highlighting the text beforehand, i.e. by clicking the combination <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> would appear to be the only option.

See answers here: [How can I run just the statement my cursor is on in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272334/any-way-to-run-just-the-current-statement-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 4):

The add-in [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/features.html#execute-current-statement) has this exact feature. Execute current statement using a hotkey without selecting it. Their free express version has it, but I also recommend standard version for its additional features. It's a major time-saver.

Answer (score 2):

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125200/execute-current-statement is a Connect issue on this - Guess it's a low priority.

I've just gotten used to using standard keyboard shortcuts. One such is to (if for example the query i want to work with is written in the end) select everything before this query using ctrl-shift-home, then ctrl-k, ctrl-c to comment this out, hit end, then f5. once i need to get all back i just ctrl-a then ctrl-k,ctrl-u to uncomment again.

In either case, it helps being familiar with the keyboard :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll have to get used to your suggestion, until they will get this funcitonality into SSMS

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 shortcuts that will perform the `Execute`, but if you have more SQL statements within the SQL file, it will execute them all unless you highlight the line you want.

`F5`
`ctrl+E`

Comment: Yes, I know these, but I want a shortcut which will execute only the current line without a need to highlight it.

Comment: I don't think there is one.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across a shortcut that will do that without selecting the row first. There isn't one listed in the [SSMS Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx) MSDN article either, so I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Home, Shift + Left click

Answer (score -2):

Here's an improvement on DaveRead's answer: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: What if the cursor is not at the end of the statement?