# How to select entire line without moving the mouse cursor

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server as database. Every time I have to fire the query in the text editor, I have to use mouse to move the cursor from start to the end.

Is there any shortcut key on keyboard which will help me to select that entire row to fire query?

Comment: ctrl+shift+end?

Comment: In SSMS, you can run the query on the current line with home, shift+end, ctrl-E.

Comment: What if my mouse is at the middle.Then I have to go to the start by home and press shift+end to select whole line. Is there any shortcut that will select whole line with a single command.

Comment: What is wrong with home -> shift + end? It is so simple that any keyboard shortcut would likely be far more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+KU</kbd> to select a line and <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd> or <kbd>Alt + X</kbd> execute  selected line.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353249/7467471